# How to check if document is open preview pane

Tags: windows, msdn, explorer, shell-extensions, deviare

I want to check or detect whether document is open in preview pane, so that i could use `setwindowdisplayaffinity()` with it. Is there any way i could start?

Comment: The preview pane is a preview of a selected document in the Windows Explorer list of documents. Not sure what you're looking for?